# Cassandra null cells != tombstoned cell count

Tags: cassandra, cql, tombstone

We are using Cassandra

```
cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.1.14.1272 | DSE 4.8.7 | CQL spec 3.2.1
```

We have around > 600000 rows where we have inserted NULLs in most of the cells for this row. We run a query which scans through 8000 rows with dates of yesterday, today,tomorrow.
However when I enabled tracing I find only :

```
Read 101 live and 997 tombstone cells [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2017-04-20 11:05:02.901000 | 10.74.70.30 |          11297
```

I know that inserting NULLs in Cassandra create tombstones for those cells but why can I only see such few tombstones even though the query is returning 8k records with each record holding multiple NULLs? Can anything explain this? The TTL for these records is 30 days by default and so this result set of 8k cannot have tombstones because of TTL.

**EDIT 1**

My schema is :

```
CREATE TABLE transportation_events.events_for_load_ops_exceptions (
    exception_phase text,
    exception_date text,
    event_id timeuuid,
    actual_delivery_ts timestamp,
    actual_pickup_ts timestamp,
    carrier_due_ts timestamp,
    carrier_id text,
    carrier_mode text,
    carrier_pickup_ts timestamp,
    dest_loc_banner_code text,
    dest_loc_class_code int,
    dest_loc_id int,
    dest_loc_name text,
    dest_loc_type text,
    dest_time_zone text,
    destination_city text,
    destination_postal_code text,
    destination_state text,
    destination_street_addr text,
    exception_type text,
    late_reason_code text,
    load_id text,
    load_type text,
    loc_time_zone text,
    orig_loc_id int,
    orig_loc_name text,
    orig_loc_type text,
    orig_time_zone text,
    origin_city text,
    origin_postal_code text,
    origin_state text,
    origin_street_addr text,
    reason_code_category text,
    reason_code_desc text,
    scheduled_delivery_ts timestamp,
    scheduled_pickup_ts timestamp,
    status_reason_code text,
    stop_loc_id int,
    stop_loc_name text,
    stop_loc_type text,
    stop_seq_num int,
    stop_type text,
    triggered_by text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((exception_phase, exception_date), event_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (event_id DESC)
```

And am saving to Cassandra by

```
import com.datastax.driver.mapping.Mapper;

 mapper.save(resultRecord);
```

I can see through CQL that is has inserted NULLs .

Query I am tracing

```
select * from transportation_events.events_for_load_ops_exceptions where exception_phase='PLANNING' AND exception_date IN ('2017-04-19','2017-04-20','2017-04-21');
```

Perhaps the compaction has removed most of the tombstones? Is there any other explanation?
 **EDIT 2** 
If there is a way to summarize and see the tombstones and their causes at once common place for the query? Like a tombstone dump for a table?

Comment: What is the schema of your table ?

Comment: And how exactly did you insert the NULL values? As far as I remember NULLs only result in tombstones when using prepared statements because Cassandra cannot distinguish between an "unset" parameter and a NULL parameter. C* versions <=2.2.0 allow you to provide a hint to the insert statement to tell C* to treat [NULL as unset](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7304).

Comment: using the mapper.save from the dse APIs automatically inserted NULLs. I could see NULLs when i queries the rows using CQLSH.

Comment: Am using Java and passing POJO

Comment: @DineMartine updated

Comment: @Tanvi : How many nodes do you have ? Only one ?

Comment: @DineMartine : 5 actually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert NULL as a value, so it will not create a tombstone.

Depending on the driver you are using, review the differences between inserting null and nulls as a value.

Another option, you can have one tombstone for hall row, or even partition, instead of one tombstone for each value.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on ur last line? Also if its not the NULLs, what else can explain these tombstones as the TTL is 30 days and i query for only 3 days worth data? I was not aware that there's a difference b/w inserting NULL and inserting NULL as a value?

Comment: For example, in python driver, if you are inserting null in prepared statement, it will be cared as a value, and will not create tombstone as it should. The easiest way to see what really going on is to do the following 1) Do your null inserts. 2) Flush. 3) See sstable dump of your latest table and see the tombstones :)

Comment: I am certain that it is creating NULLs.I am using a DSE mapper which y default adds NULL which should according to me result in tombstones. But my question is why is there a discrepancy in the number of tombstones? If there are 5 nULLs in 1 row i was expecting 5 tombstones. But the numbers dont match here.

Comment: As i told, you can have less tombstones than nulls, because you can have 1 tombstone representing several null values, or even row range. So do an sstable dump and see whats in there. If you have problems understanding contents, add them to question.

Comment: Alright. But when I truncated the table on another environment, inserted only 1 row with 8 cells as NON NULL and rest of the 35 cells as NULL, I had found 35 tombstones while querying. Is this a configuration somewhere to dictate how tombstones are created? Whether they are at a cell level, or a row range or any other way

Comment: Range tombstones created by deletes,  range deletes, or putting nulls for all values in a row, can create 1 tombstone hall row, for example. There's many ways why tombstones are created for range of rows, for partition , or not created at all (tombstoned data for example). This is why i've asked you to review the dump of the sstable with tombstones.